# Force MacBook to turn on when low battery indicator is showing

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

i copied some files to a USB drive with 8 minutes left of battery and then closed the lid. 30 seconds later I realised I missed a file and reopened my MacBook to be presented with the low battery indicator. Seeing as I had 8 minutes left is there a way to force the MacBook to turn on so I can take a few seconds to copy the missing file. I need the file quite urgently

Comment: The 8 minutes is an indication and can be far from the amount of time you can use it in real life. If your Mac does not get out of sleep it means the battery is really dead and you will need a charger.

Comment: I got to a plug half an hour later, plugged it in, turned it back on, unplugged it and it lasted about 6 or 7 minutes. So the 8 minutes wasn't far off at all. And it was only plugged in for the minute it took to turn on.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this, but I can imagine it takes more power to start up than it costs to run idle for 8 minutes. Because of this you could not start your mac, even though you still had "8 minutes" of juice. The next time you only have 10 minutes left of your battery try running some computationally intensive task (e.g. rendering a video). You'll notice that you'll not get the full 10 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no way to force it to turn on - except by plugging in the charger, which you seem to not want.